# grails reflection - Calling a dynamic tag

Tags: grails, reflection

I know this is odd, but I'm trying to provide a pass through interface in a taglib that allows the caller to pass in any other tag to be displayed in a container with additional processing.

To this effect, I'm trying to dynamically call an arbitrary tag in an arbitrary namespace.  This may be clearer by example.

GSP:

```
<myLib:myTag someProp="blah" anotherProp="blah2" size="80" namespace="g" tag="textField">
```

In my taglib, I'm trying to display the tag they pass.

Taglib:

```
def myTag = {
  String id = //some processing, not specified by caller
  attrs.put("id", id)
  def namespace = attrs.remove("namespace")
  def tag = attrs.remove("tag")
  out << ?????
}
```

The problem comes after the out...  I'm having trouble calling the tag.  I've tried the following with the following errors

```
namespace.tag(attrs) //No signature of method: java.lang.String.tag()
namespace."${tag}"(attrs) //No signature of method: java.lang.String.textField()
"${namespace}"."${tag}"(attrs) //No signature of method: java.lang.String.textField()
```

This seems to work, but the method needs to support tags in other namespaces

```
g."${tag}"(attrs)
```

So the question is **How can I use reflection to use a dynamically defined taglib?**

I don't have them pass the fully formed tag in the body() because I need to interact with it in the taglib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following works, I'm not completely certain this is the best answer, so will leave the question open for suggestions from others.

```
String namespace = attrs.remove("namespace")
String tag = attrs.remove("tag")
GrailsTagLibClass tagLibClass = grailsApplication.getTagLibClasses().find { it.namespace == namespace && it.hasTag(tag)}
def tagLibBean = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(tagLibClass.getFullName())
out << tagLibBean."${tag}"(attrs)
```